# ispell breaks my org-mode headings folding/unfolding

Tags: org-mode, osx, ispell

As the title says, when I run M-x ispell when it reaches a word that is under an org mode heading it won't unfold the heading, so my cursor is on the actual heading and not the incorrect word and then when i quit ispell i can't unfold that heading with tab. I have to kill and yank the heading to get it working again.

- I have also tried this with emacs -q and get the same issue.
- I'm using emacs+ on mac

**UPDATE FROM BUG REPORT**

> At this point, I feel that supporting isearch + text properties is an uphill battle. I was hoping to contribute isearch.el patch upstream, but apparently numerous other libraries (ispell, regexp-search, evil, swiper) are relying upon invisibility being handled in very specific way, using overlays. Considering that using overlays is no longer slower compared to text properties in Emacs 29+, I am thinking of slowly switching back to using overlays for folding for newer Emacs versions.
>
> For your problem, just add (setq org-fold-core-style 'overlays) early in your config. It should fix the issue.

Comment: If you see something with `emacs -Q` that breaks something that's also vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`), then report it as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. That's not a question.

Comment: will do thanks, hopefully gets fixed soon.

Comment: Yes, please report it: I can reproduce it as well.

Comment: reported. I'll update this post when i hear back